# how to match the number with % from df -k command

Tags: text-processing, disk-usage

in my bash script I want to print the use capacity of /var partition from df -k command

I do the following

```
     df -k | grep var | awk '{print $5}'
```

the problem is that sometimes "use%" number exists on the four field and sometimes on the fifth and sometimes on other field as six or more

so I want to match the **NUMBER%** of var partition

please advice how to match the use% number of var partition ( elegant way )

Thanks

example1

```
df -k

Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             13204256   4247972   8274728  34% /
/dev/sda5              5080796    141540   4677000   3% /tmp
/dev/sda2             14013128   7578564   5711240  58% /var
/dev/sda1               194442     40649    143754  23% /boot
tmpfs                  1037756         0   1037756   0% /dev/shm
```

example2

```
 df -k

  Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
  /dev/mapper/SysGroup-lv_root
                  18578172   2680752  14953704  16% /
  tmpfs                   510240         0    510240   0% /dev/shm
  /dev/sda1               198337     50064    138033  27% /boot
  /dev/mapper/SysGroup-lv_tmp
                   5160576    141464   4756968   3% /tmp
  /dev/mapper/SysGroup-lv_var
                  28899452   3481568  23949880  13% /var
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about pure grep solution?

```
df -k | grep var | grep -o '[0-9]*%'
```

You can then join those two greps with a little help of perl regexp:

```
df -k | grep -Po 'var.* \K[0-9]*%'
```

Comment: Ops, sorry, you posted your answer while I was writing mine. I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to match the % number:

```
df -k | grep -E ' /run$' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+%'
```

Some explanation.

```
df -k
```

- Self explanator: it shows the disk free table

  grep -E ' /var$'
- Use the extended regexp engine with `grep` to match the `/var` mountponit
- The regular expression `/var$` anchor the pattern to the end of line so it doesn't matches any `/var/run`, `/var/tmp` which a simple `grep var` would. Also note the space before the slash.

  grep -Eo '[0-9]+%'

  - `-E` will enable PCRE regular expression in Grep
  - `-o` will print only the matching string

The regular expression is quite simple:

- `[0-9]` match any digit
- `+`     means will match at least one digit
- `%`     will match `%` char

Sample output:

```
$ df -k | grep -E ' /var$' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+%'
1%
```

Good part is that it doesn't matter at which position the Use% is.

If your grep support PCRE regular expressions (Mac OSX doesn't, for example), you can use a single regexp:

```
df -h | grep -Po '[0-9]+%(?= /var$)'
```

This uses Perl regexp, and use the "look behind" to anchor to the pattern `/var$` and match the regexp.
If you are curious you can read something about this feature on [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the elegant solution you need:

If you just want the /var, then

```
df --output=pcent /var
```

If you want to rather use grep

```
df --output=source,pcent | grep var
```

Or you can use the posix format where the fifth field is always Use%

```
df -k --portability | grep var | awk '{print $5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
.... | awk '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

This can cause the header of `df` output to be printed if it contains the `grep` pattern. To avoid this, you can:

```
.... | awk '$(NF-1) ~ /%/'
```

A more general way, POSIXly, use `-P` option of [df](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html#tag_20_33_10):

```
df -P | .... | awk '{print $5}'
```